# Evaluate $x$ for $2x^2 - 3x - 2<0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve $$2x^2-3x-2=0$$ we get $x=-0.5;2$

So, $$-0.5<x<2$$
The key answer is $$0.5<x<2$$
Which one is true?

Comment: Your title question and your imperative that begins your post are not the same.  It looks like you need to solve the *inequality* as given in the title, not the equation you write in your post.   While it is certainly helpful to solve for equality, you then need to test for the intervals defined by those points which make the inequality true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Factorizing, we get $$2x^2-3x-2=(2x+1)(x-2).$$

Its roots are $-\frac12$ and $2$.  Using a tabular method, we have
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{Interval} & 2x+1 & x-2 & \text{Sign of}\ f(x)\\
\hline
x<-\frac12 & - & - & +\\
\hline
x=-\frac12 & 0 & - & 0\\
\hline
\color{blue}{-\frac12 < x < 2} & + & - & \color{blue}{-}\\
\hline
x=2 & + & 0 & 0\\
\hline
x>2 & + & + & +\\
\hline
\end{array}

Therefore, the answer should be $\boxed{-\frac12<x<2}$.

Answer (score -1):

The correct answer is $-0.5<x<2$.  There should be a negative sign in the key answer.

The inequality holds for all $x$ between the zeroes, including for example $x=0$.

Comment: Please post a complete answer, and not an answer in progress...doubling or tripling your word count every minute after your initial post.